# ADO & DBGrid/ FireMonkey in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I would buy the new Delphi XE2 and port some D7 projects. I would buy the cheapest version (**starter** ?) and use the new Firemonkey Platform. 
1/ I use the ADODB for MDB databases is this version compatible with it ?
2/ It seems that there is no DBGrid in Firemonkey is it true ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) I use the ADODB for MDB databases is this version compatible with it?

A:Yes  you can still using ADO in a FireMonkey or VCL application in Delphi XE2. But only if your [delphi edition is not Starter](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/41563/Delphi_XE2_Feature_Matrix.pdf).

2) It seems that there is no DBGrid in Firemonkey is it true ?

A: Yes is true, but now using [`LiveBindings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio) you could bind your data to a [`TStringGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/FMX.Grid.TStringGrid) or a [`TGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/FMX.Grid.TGrid).

Comment: For ADO are you sure that Starter version is OK ?

Comment: I just check the feature matrix for delphi xe2 (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/41563/Delphi_XE2_Feature_Matrix.pdf) and it seems which the DbGO components (ADO) are not included in the Starter Edition.